# Is it a good idea to store GUI elements in a module on runtime?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in wxpython, and to make GUI parts that are built in different modules I made a module called `runtime`, where all the GUI parts get stored on runtime.
This is how it looks:

```
mainFrame = anotherGUIPart = InputDialog = SomethingElse = None
```

For example, when I need to make a ListControl to update itself, I use

```
#anotherGUIPart.py
class AnotherGUIPart(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.listCtrl = wx.ListCtrl(self,
                 style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        ...
    def UpdateList(self):
        self.listCtrl.DeleteAllItems()
        ...

#Somewhere where I need to update the list
import runtime
runtime.anotherGUIPart.UpdateList()
```

Is this a good practice?
If not, what are alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, as long as you're not bleeding too much across the module boundaries. Ideally you would have a structure somewhat akin to MVC, where you have all of your UI logic in one module, all your business logic in another, and a controller module which links the two together. However, if you find that this improves your ability to understand the code then that's just fine. If you post a link to more of your code it'll be easier to review the design as this is quite macro-scale.